# Realm migration not called

Tags: ios, swift, migration, realm

I've added a value to a realm object (I've added dynamic var inspectorName = "" to the WeekReport object), and I'm trying to migrate the realm database to contain that value. I'm trying to call the migration block in `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil)` like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    print("HERE")
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
        schemaVersion: 1,
        migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: WeekReport.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    newObject!["inspectorName"] = ""
                }
            }
    })

    return true
}
```

But it seems that `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` isn't called before my error happens.

In multiple view controller i have `let realm = try! Realm()`. Here Xcode breaks when I run the app:

> "Migration is required due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'WeekReport.inspectorName' has been added." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'WeekReport.inspectorName' has been added., Error Code=10}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.63/src/swift/

**How come the migration blick isn't called?** "HERE" is never printed...

Should I define realm in a different way in my view controllers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you write `let realm = try! Realm()` in a view controller as an instance variable, it will be called before `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from Storyboard. To resolve this, you can use `lazy var realm = try! Realm()` instead. `lazy` defers creating an instance variable until the variable is accessed.

Comment: No. I have same problem here. I put try! Realm in didLoad and make sure it is only called after setting Configuration.default. Still get same crash and error message as @Wiingaard. The code in migrationBlock of Realm.Configuration was not executed even I directly call Realm.performMigration

Comment: Switching it from `let realm = try! Realm()` to `lazy var realm = try! Realm()` did the trick for me.

Comment: Hey guys, any luck to fix as I'm working on a pre-coded project and it has lot of screens creating realm object from so many events like reachability, app become active, first screen, so many notifiers. I really need a help on this to fix as my migration block not get called in any case. @kishikawa katsumi. Please share your solution

Comment: @Anson Yao please share if you had fixed

Answer (score 3):

In my case `schemaVersion: 1`, was to low and migration block was never called. Make sure that your new version is greater then previous.

It was my first migration but I had to change it to `schemaVersion: 2` and then it started working.

Answer (score 2):

> In multiple view controller i have `let realm = try! Realm()`.

It seems like one of your view controllers creates Realm before `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, so the default configuration with migration is not set by that time.

Make sure that you configure `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration` before any instances of Realm are created.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, try calling:

```
 _ = try! Realm()
```

before:

```
return true
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is the migration is an async call and we can only access the Realm after the migration is completed. So the flow should be first: Set the configuration. Second: Use Realm.asyncOpen to force Realm update and hold off other things which may access try! Realm(). You can find more details here:
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#asynchronously-opening-realms