# realm migration, cannot add property

Tags: swift, realm, realm-migration

testing realm, cannot add a new property to my testing class. Followed documentation and some answer here but both are not working. In my code even the "plain" empty default block for migration is not working, using updated realm.

getting this error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'ComicType.creationDate' has been added." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Migration is required due to the following errors:
>   - Property 'ComicType.creationDate' has been added., Error Code=10}

it seems I'm not changing the schemaVersion, but I did in the "basic" migration block. I check the schema version in app delegate with:

```
 let configCheck = Realm.Configuration();
        do {
            let fileUrlIs = try schemaVersionAtURL(configCheck.fileURL!)
            print("schema version \(fileUrlIs)")
        } catch  {
            print(error)
        }
```

my AppDelegate:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.


        let config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 1, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

                if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
                }

        })

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

        _ = try! Realm()



        return true
    }
```

my class:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ComicType: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var creationDate : Date? //the new property

}
```

Comment: Please specify _"not working"_. You don't need to do anything in your migration block, Realm can handle a simple migration like this (adding a new property with a default value), so there must be something else going on if an empty migration block didn't work.

Comment: added the error message

Comment: Are you sure your `schemaVersion` just needs to be 1? Is this your first migration?

Comment: yes, it  is a test app, everything went right editing objects, but testing migration scripts I cannot get rid of this error.

Comment: As a test, I copied and pasted your code into a project, with the ComicType original creationDate property. In code I added a few objects. I then commented out the old CreationDate and uncommented the new one, changed the schemaVersion to 2 and ran the code. It worked fine. I then made a number of changes (adding & removing properties etc) to the ComicType object, updating the migration number each time and it worked correctly. Also, what are you expecting by changing an optional var *Date? = nil* to another optional var *creationDate : Date?*. That change doesn't require a migration.

Comment: maybe I’m doing something wrong, same error in a different project, class Person, with a name string. Save and read some object, all ok, then adding age as int to the class, then apply the “plain” code in app delegate with 1 at both values, error, so modified to “2” the first value, error again.
about your question, I did not find how to simply add an optional, so I tried to give the initial value as per operational handling in Realm, nothing more. I my project the CreationDate was added as new property, is there a way to reset the schema version e try all over again?

Comment: added code to check current schema version, it seems the script is not working at all, the schema version change is not recorded, it is always 0

Answer (score 3):

Issue solved this way: the real issue is not about schema number, but about not calling at all the migration code, I realized the migration schema remained always the same. True error is calling `let realm = try! Realm()` in my view controller using it as global constant. Now using     `lazy var realm = try! Realm()` Great help found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727978/realm-migration-not-called?rq=1) . Now after each change in my model, I update in appDelegate the schemaVersion.

Comment: The migration code is not being called as there is nothing to migrate per my comment to your question. An optional is an optional so telling an nil optional to be nil isn't doing anything, therefore there's nothing to migrate. In other words, the type of variable is not being changed to anything different so the migration code will not be called.

Comment: I think we misunderstood  each other and therefore the issue. Original model only had name. In a second Moment I tried to add the date. Both of them are tests to make work the migration block.

Answer (score 1):

### What worked for was to remove the app from the iOS Simulator, and then run it again using XCode. More about this is found here: https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat.iOS/issues/104

I was facing a similar issue, my error stack trace was beginning like this:

```
`fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=io.realm Code=10 "Migration is required due to the following errors:
```

The errors shown was just confirming the some objects have been saved locally. so, there was no clue on what caused the problem.

What I figured was, the issue was that the schema of Realm Database was violated, since I updated the Objects' classes that I have been saving locally. So, it requested that I update the schema.

I suppose that a new Realm file with is created when the app is removed and run again. If so, then a new schema is created that works with latest code